# Is it possible to have a evolving/changing source(form part) for a select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm dealing with an issue, I have a stored procedure to create on a database.

By entering an id, I need to receive data about a product. However this product can be separated in two and at this moment we add a letter to the ID (A or B or ...).

The problem is that this additional letter is managed in a column for each table in the database.

And some separate products, (so with ID + letter) do not necessarily have a corresponding value in the database for ID + letter, in this case I need at least the result of the ID (without the letter)

I wonder if it is possible to use a CASE in the FROM part of a query, or if another solution is available.

```
--Brief example but is working 
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN RandomTab1WithLetter.RandomValue1 IS NOT NULL THEN
    RandomTab1WithLetter.RandomValue1
    ELSE RandomTab1.RandomValue1
END AS WantedValue1    
FROM RandomView1
LEFT JOIN RandomTab1 ON RandomView1.ID = RandomTab1.ID 
LEFT JOIN RandomTab1WithLetter
ON COALESCE(RandomView1.ID,'') + COALESCE(RandomView1.ID_BIS,'') =
COALESCE(RandomTab1WithLetter.ID,'') + COALESCE(RandomTab1WithLetter.ID_BIS,'')
```

Example of what I'm looking for

RandomView

| ID | IDBIS |
| --- | --- |
| 666665 |  |
| 666666 | A |
| 666666 | B |
| 666667 | A |
| 666667 | B |

RandomTab1

| ID | IDBIS | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 666665 |  | 12 |
| 666666 | A | 14 |
| 666666 | B | 16 |
| 666667 |  | 30 |

Results wanted with ID + IDBIS on parameters

| ID | IDBIS | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 |  | 12 |
| 555 | A | 14 |
| 555 | B | 16 |
| 888 | A | 30 |
| 888 | B | 30 |

Comment: Sounds like, in truth, that you should have the ID and the letter in different columns, then you can perform, the `JOIN` much more easily.

Comment: Could you get us some sample data (in text form, not an image) and an example of the desired output for that data so we can see what you mean?

Comment: Also, will you always pass in a letter or sometimes not, and if not do you want returned all the matching ID regardless of letter or only the ID with no letter? And will letter be NULL or EmptyString if not specified?

Comment: @RobertSheahan I updated my question, I hope it will be clearer now. 
About the letter, sometimes there will be no letter in parameters and in database, and when an ID does not have a assciated letter, this value is "" (not nul but empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach is to use a left join to the table twice, and then use COALESCE to pick the best available match

```
with cteView as ( --SAMPLE DATA: Your "View"
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES ('1','A','Widgets'), ('1','C','Widgets'), ('1','','Widgets')
        , ('2','B','Gadgets'), ('2','C','Gadgets'), ('2','','Gadgets')
    ) as ViewDef(ID, ID_BIS, ProdName)
), cteTab1 as (--SAMPLE DATA: Your "View"
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('1','A','Type A Widgets'), ('1','B','Type B Widgets'), ('1','','Generic Widgets')
        , ('2','A','Type A Gadgets'), ('2','B','Type B Gadgets'), ('2','','Generic Gadgets')
        , ('3','A','Type A Gizmos'), ('3','B','Type B Gizmos'), ('3','','Generic Gizmos')
    ) as ViewDef(ID, ID_BIS, ProdDescript)
)--Your real query begins here
SELECT V.* --Show what' sin your VIEW, then choose the bast match available
    , COALESCE(Best.ProdDescript, Weak.ProdDescript,'Product not found') as ReturnDescription
    , '-----------' as Alternates --This and below for debugging so you can see choices
    , Best.ProdDescript as BestProdDescript, Weak.ProdDescript as WeakProdDescript
FROM cteView as V --Basic view
    --This is non-null if you have an exact match
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteTab1 as Best on V.ID = Best.ID 
            AND V.ID_BIS = Best.ID_BIS --IF USING EMPTY use this
            --AND (V.ID_BIS = Best.ID_BIS OR (V.ID_BIS IS NULL AND Best.ID_BIS IS NULL)) --IF USING NULL use this
    --This is non-null if you have a weak match
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteTab1 as Weak on V.ID = Weak.ID 
            AND V.ID_BIS != '' AND  Weak.ID_BIS = '' --IF USING EMPTY use this
            --AND (V.ID_BIS IS NOT NULL AND Weak.ID_BIS IS NULL)--IF USING NULL use this
```

gives the following result

| ID | ID_BIS | ProdName | ReturnDescription | Alternates | BestProdDescript | WeakProdDescript |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Widgets | Type A Widgets | ----------- | Type A Widgets | Generic Widgets |
| 1 | C | Widgets | Generic Widgets | ----------- | NULL | Generic Widgets |
| 1 |  | Widgets | Generic Widgets | ----------- | Generic Widgets | NULL |
| 2 | B | Gadgets | Type B Gadgets | ----------- | Type B Gadgets | Generic Gadgets |
| 2 | C | Gadgets | Generic Gadgets | ----------- | NULL | Generic Gadgets |
| 2 |  | Gadgets | Generic Gadgets | ----------- | Generic Gadgets | NULL |

EDIT: Plugging in the data you supplied does give the results you listed as desired:

```
;with cteView as ( --SAMPLE DATA: Your "View"
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES ('666665','','Widgets'), ('666666','A','Widgets'), ('666666','B','Widgets')
        , ('666667','A','Gadgets'), ('666667','B','Gadgets')
    ) as ViewDef(ID, ID_BIS, ProdName)
), cteTab1 as (--SAMPLE DATA: Your "View"
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('666665','','12'), ('666666','A','14'), ('666666','B','16')
        , ('666667','','30')
    ) as ViewDef(ID, ID_BIS, ProdDescript)
)--Your real query begins here
SELECT V.* --Show what' sin your VIEW, then choose the bast match available
    , COALESCE(Best.ProdDescript, Weak.ProdDescript,'Product not found') as ReturnDescription
    , '-----------' as Alternates --This and below for debugging so you can see choices
    , Best.ProdDescript as BestProdDescript, Weak.ProdDescript as WeakProdDescript
FROM cteView as V --Basic view
    --This is non-null if you have an exact match
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteTab1 as Best on V.ID = Best.ID 
            AND V.ID_BIS = Best.ID_BIS --IF USING EMPTY use this
            --AND (V.ID_BIS = Best.ID_BIS OR (V.ID_BIS IS NULL AND Best.ID_BIS IS NULL)) --IF USING NULL use this
    --This is non-null if you have a weak match
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteTab1 as Weak on V.ID = Weak.ID 
            AND V.ID_BIS != '' AND  Weak.ID_BIS = '' --IF USING EMPTY use this
            --AND (V.ID_BIS IS NOT NULL AND Weak.ID_BIS IS NULL)--IF USING NULL use this
```

Gives result

| ID | ID_BIS | ProdName | ReturnDescription | Alternates | BestProdDescript | WeakProdDescript |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 666665 |  | Widgets | 12 | ----------- | 12 | NULL |
| 666666 | A | Widgets | 14 | ----------- | 14 | NULL |
| 666666 | B | Widgets | 16 | ----------- | 16 | NULL |
| 666667 | A | Gadgets | 30 | ----------- | NULL | 30 |
| 666667 | B | Gadgets | 30 | ----------- | NULL | 30 |